# Unable to adjust alignment of handlebars

Tags: handlebars, city, alignment

I have a Dutch build Gazelle Superior Special that is a rather old bicycle. I have noticed that the handlebars are no longer fully aligned with the front wheel. I have decided to remove the threaded bolts in the hopes that I can adjust the direction of the handlebars. See below:

[image]

This reveals a single ball joint with grooves for adjusting the handlebar pitch. In the center is a single long bolt:

[image]

I have removed the bolt in the hopes that I can swivel the ball joint. However it is completely immovable and I cannot adjust the direction it points.

[image]

Is anyone familiar with this system? I do not have a stem I can change. I am unsure if I am simply not applying enough force, or if there is some other mechanism on this bicycle design for adjusting the orientation. There is very little information or discussion I can find on this particular bicycle model.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Have a search in the internet how to free a stuck quill stem. [Reading this might help](https://sheldonbrown.com/brandt/stuck-stem.html)

Comment: @mattnz It seems that people have to go to quite some lengths to free frozen quill stems . Should I just take it to a shop if I can't loosen it with percussive persuasion? It's not that misaligned in the end. I guess I could live with it.

Comment: Depends on the design of the quill (can't guess about this one) and what's particularly stuck down below.  Sometimes screwing the bolt part way in and then giving it a whack downward with a hammer will loosen the wedge at the bottom.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Alright, I will try this approach.

Comment: Nothing is every so broken you cannot make it worse :)  If you can live with it, don't hit it too hard before giving up.

Comment: Please don’t ride a bike with misaligned handlebar. It’s neither comfortable nor safe.

Comment: That there is obvious rust on the heatset nut shows the likely conditions inside the headset, where the wedge is.  You're battling corrosion here.   Given this question is now over a year old, can you add an update? @Michael

Comment: The usual Dutch way to adjust the handle bar is to stand in front of the handle bars with the wheel between your legs. 
Hold the wheel steady with the legs and grip the handle bars and adjust slowly till they are in the right straight compared to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture of a stem similar to, but not exactly like, your stem.

[image]

The key thing to note is the wedge at the lower end of the stem. By tightening the long Allan bolt the wedge jams the stem into the steering tube holding it tight, but the wedge can become seized.

Removing the stem involves freeing the seized wedge, by loosening the long Allan bolt and whacking it with a hammer.

In your case you could have loosened the wedge by inserting an Allan wrench into the hole visible in your first picture that allows you to tighten or loosen the long Allan bolt - loosen the bolt and then give it a whack.

It's always best to coat the wedge all over with a thin layer of grease on re-assembly

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, the handlebar is not at a right-angle to the front wheel? If that is the case, you can just hold the wheel between your legs and adjust it. Just put some (reasonable, not excessive) force on it. If it is about the steering itself, that should be up or down, it was just a screw under it that you should loosen a bit and then you can adjust it.

Comment: Thanks for your late answer. I was never able to correct the offset unfortunately. I feel like perhaps the ball joint is frozen to the stem. That is the less glamour conclusion to my question I guess.

Comment: Hi and welcome to bicycles.  "Just force it" is rarely the optimal solution; if it is tight this is a recipe for bending the wheel, rather than fixing the steering.

Comment: I was clearly commenting on the use of force in a balanced way, without being excessive. But I appreciate the comment. Anyway, I hope you can fix it, and if not. Hopefully the bicycle works a bit more.